# Stop div block from moving

Tags: html

I'm having trouble controlling the position of div blocks. Here is the html code.

```
<div id="d1">
    <div id="d2">
        <div id="d3" style="float:left" >
            <img src="image.jpg" > 
        </div>

        <div id="d4">
            Lorem Ipsum .... Dummy Text
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="d5">
        Stop this text from moving up
    </div>
</div>
```

I want d3 and d4 to be 2 parallel columns, and d5 should come beneath both of these, sort of like footer in most websites. So when I add the float:left style to div d3, the d5 text moves up just under the "Lorem Ipsum" text. How can I have the 2 column working, and make the  position of d5 fixed? Its pretty basic, but I'm not sure what I'm missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding a clear:both; to the div with the id 'd5'

in your css for example;

```
div#d5
{
    clear:both;
}
```

more information about this css attribute can be found [here](http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_class_clear.asp)

Comment: This was simple enough. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just the 'float: left' doesn't do the trick. You'll have to add a width or something to #d3 and make #d4 floating (with width) as well.

#d5 would then need some styling like 'clear: both;' to position it below the #d3 & #d4 column. If you want to have it positioned fixed to the bottom of the browserscreen, add 'position: fixed; bottom: 0;'.
Also, the #d2 div isn't required.